# Java Project Ant to Maven Migration

Tags: java, git, maven, ant, migration

I am migrating a very old project that is built through ANT and is version managed in GIT.
I am migrating to Maven.
Question : Because the new folder project structure is going to follow the Maven Standard Layout that is very different from the actual one, what is the best way to commit and push to GIT ? i am asking this because git will think all the files are to be deleted (they are not in the same folder) and all the files are new (because they are in new folders).

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move entire folders in GIT. And GIT is better at tracking history of these types of moves then say SVN. I did a folder move just the other day `git mv src\test\folder\subfolder src\test\`

TortoiseGIT shows the file change as a renamed files and shows the original file path.